# Write is.numeric output into a function

Tags: r, if-statement, boolean

I have a very simple question. I want to create a function that returns `TRUE` if there is a positive numeric object, `FALSE` if it is not, and `"Insert a number"` if the object is, for instance, a character vector. I wrote this:

```
check.positive<-function(x){
  if(all(x>=0)){
    cat("TRUE")
  }else if(all(x<0)){
    cat("FALSE")
  }else if(is.numeric(x)==FALSE){
    cat("Insert a number")
  }
}
```

It works for checking if a number is positive or negative but it doesn't work if I try with a character vector. I guess this `(is.numeric(x)==FALSE)` is not the correct argument for the if statement but I am not sure how to formulate this. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: You should start by checking if x is numeric or not since the comparision you do only make sense for numeric variables and instead of `is.numeric(x) == FALSE` you can use simply `!is.numeric(x)`.

Comment: You said you want to create a function that returns a value … but the code you’ve shown returns nothing, it merely *prints* the result. (In general that isn’t very useful; returning a result is generally what you’d want to do.)

Answer (score 2):

```
check.positive<-function(x){
  if(is.numeric(x)){
    if(all(x>=0)){
      cat("TRUE")
    }else if(all(x<0)){
      cat("FALSE")}
  }else{
    cat("Insert a number")
  }
}
```

> ```
> > check.positive("c")
> Insert a number
> > check.positive(1)
> TRUE
> > check.positive(-2)
> FALSE
> ```

Comment: Adding text to your answer to explain the logic makes these infinitely more useful for the one answering the question and future users looking for solution to similar problems. This doesn't require much, just 1 -  2 lines can help a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Alter the order. Note that `"A" > 0` returns `TRUE`. That is because in programming all characters are assigned a numeric value, and a string is thus just a vector of numeric values (from a programming standpoint). So all type-checking should come **first** in your functions (this is also good programming practice):

```
check.positive <- function(x){
  if(!is.numeric(x))
   cat("Insert a number")
  else if(all(x >= 0))
   cat("TRUE")
  else if(all(x < 0))
   cat("FALSE")
}
```

Comment: Thank you Oliver, I didn't know that and this will be very useful! A quick question: I noticed you didn't use {} brackets, is there a particular reason? I tried and it works both with and without brackets.

Comment: My pleasure. It's programming specific. In R (and C++) you can leave out the brackets if the statement only affects the next (or current) line. Eg `if(FALSE) print("HELLO WORLD"); print("i am not part of the statement")` will only print the latter  (`;` indicates the end of a statement in R). If you have more than 1 thing affected by the `if`/`function` statement, you need the braces. :-)

Comment: Note it can get confusing if you have nested conditions (2 or more `if-else`). So in general I would suggest being strict with your brackets. Even after having a few years under your belt it can lead to very confusing (unexpected) behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. Implementing all your suggestions (return a result and not just print, alter the order, etc) I got:

```
check.positive <- function(x){
  if(!is.numeric(x)){
    result<-"Insert a number"
  }else if(all(x >= 0)){
    result<-"TRUE"
  }else if(all(x < 0)){
    result<-"FALSE"
  }
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: Normally in “typical” R code wouldn’t perform the assignment inside the `if` branches, you would perform it *outside*. (i.e. `result = if (…) a else if (…) b else c`). Furthermore, there’s no need to call the `return` function here, you can return the result directly. And that, in turn, means that the `result` variable is redundant. Therefore, an idiomatic solution would look as follows: `check_positive = function (x) { if (! is.numeric(x)) 'insert a number' else if (all(x >= 0)) 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' }`.—Furthermore, instead of returning a string it’s generally more helpful to return a logical.

Comment: … but if you return a logical value it’s not clear how you would represent the first case. One solution would be to return `NA`. This ultimately depends on how this function is actually used. One last note: function names are more readable when they describe what the function does. `check.positive` is not very descriptive. `is_positive` is better (but then it *must* return a logical value, returning character strings would make this name misleading). I can’t think of a good name for this function returning strings, which is another sign that that the current functionality is ill-defined.

Comment: Dear Konrad, thanks a lot. So, based on your suggestions, this would be better: `is.positive <- function(x){
  if(!is.numeric(x)){
    NA
  }else if(all(x >= 0)){
    TRUE
  }else if(all(x < 0)){
    FALSE
  }
}`

Comment: That’s certainly how *I* would write such a function. But, to repeat, this also depends on the code *calling* the function (since it obviously does something quite different now). But I basically never write functions that return strings, except to display these strings directly to the user. I never use strings to encode code-internal values (that’s an [anti-pattern](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/31876/stringly-typed)), I use whichever type is most appropriate *for the code*.